# Running java file with external jars in linux

Tags: java, linux

How to run a java file that has external jars in Linux. Also how to run it in Windows?

I tried the following, but not working.

```
javac -cp c:/lib/lib1.jar;c:/lib/lib2.jar c:/com/example/Application.java
```

thanks

------EDITED------

Now my class file got generated after compiling without any error. But when i run the  file its showing following error

java -cp C:/lib/lib1.jar;C:/lib/lib2.jar C:/com/example/Application

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: C:/com/example/Application
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: C:/com/example/Application
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
```

Any suggestion...

Comment: Linux doesn't have a `c:/` path (last time i checked) and the path separator isn't `;`

Comment: She is asking how to run in on Windows

Comment: She is asking both. And the answer is: Check the right way to write the paths on each system

Comment: What errors are you getting on Windows with the above command?

Comment: @ MadProgrammer: I tried it for Windows

Answer (score 1):

If you are running on linux, then there should be different directory structure from windows. Also the classpath on linux should contains paths separated path by colon(`:`) instead of semi-colon(`;`)

Put your jars in a directory on linux machines, may be in /var/tmp/myjars. And then compile your code using the below command:

```
javac -cp /var/tmp/myjars/lib1.jar;/var/tmp/myjars/lib2.jar Application.java
```

**EDIT**
As you have updated your question. You need to run your class on windows as mentioned here. I am taking few assumptions here that your Application class is in com.example package. If that is the case then you can run it from the folder containing the com folder as mentioned here:

```
java -cp C:/lib/lib1.jar;C:/lib/lib2.jar com.example.Application
```

Comment: @user2670291 updated my answer, again with few assumption ;-)

Answer (score 0):

`javac` is the Java compiler. after compiling the program the running on windows should work like this

```
java -cp c:/lib/lib1.jar;c:/lib/lib2.jar c:/com/example/Application
```

Comment: I am getting error in running the file. Please see my edited part in the actual post

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

java -cp classpath=%classpath%;< jar-file full-path>; ClassName

Ex: java -cp classpath=%classpath%;c:/lib/lib1.jar;c:/lib/lib2.jar com.ab.cd.MyClass